# How to concatenate different latex files

Tags: pdfpages, tufte

Suppose I wrote several latex files, resulting with several pdf files that I want to concatenate together.

Now suppose that different latex files are written with different templates and packages and I do not want to mess up with latex files too much. What would be the cleanest way to concatenate these files?

Would the case of the same template to write pdf files - such as tufte-latex - make concatenation easier?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, the `pdfpages` packages might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to simply put all the pdfs together, you can use this basic code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

% first page of the pdf
\includepdf{document-title}

% all pages
\includepdf[pages=-]{document-title}

% all pages starting from page 2 
\includepdf[pages=2-]{document-title}

\end{document}
```

For more information, look here: [pdfpages documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).

This will not change your LaTeX files at all. However, in the resulting pdf hyperlinks will not work. (Also, page numbering etc. will not change.)

(As mentioned by @leandriis)

Comment: Note that _some_ things such as hyperlink (and drop shadows -- been meaning to file a question about this, but haven't done it yet) will be missing in the pdf generated with `pdfpages`.

Comment: That's true, I added the hyperlink part.